# Lagrange multipliers implementation (beginner question)

Tags: mathematical-optimization, broken-code

I am trying to write a code to find the minimum of $f(x,y) = (Mx + Ny) \,/\sqrt{M^2 x + N^2 y}$?, subject to the constraint $g(x,y)=x+y-1$. Also, $x,y>0$, and $M$ and $N$ are positive constants.

My code looks like this:

```
f[x_, y_] := 
  (Mx + Ny)/Sqrt[M^2 x + N^2 y] := 
     Boole[x > 0 && y > 0 && M > 0 && N > 0]
g[x_, y_] := x + y - 1
Minimize[{f[x, y], g[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}]
```

However the output I get is:

```
{$Failed, {x -> 0, y -> 1}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

(Also, why is $N$ not colored in $N>0$ and $N^2y$)

(See also [my next question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95343/8))

Comment: To answer your last question: Don't use capital letters as variable names, because all built-in *Mathematica* functions are capitalized. In particular, `N` already has a built-in meaning. That is why `N` shows up in black. In the future, if such a thing occurs, you can highlight the name, click F1, and it will take you the documentation on the function (which you should be using all the time!).

Comment: Further, `Mx` is a identifier not the expression `M*x` (also written `M x`).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] := (M x + n y)/Sqrt[M^2 x + n^2 y]
g[x_, y_] := x + y - 1
Minimize[{f[x, y], g[x, y] == 0, M > 0, n > 0, x > 0, y > 0}, {x, y}]
```

Comment: `N` is a reserved word in Mathematica. Never start your own symbols with capitals

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm trying to make the same function for 3 variable (see above). But I've been waiting for some time and still running with no answer, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @odnerpmocon Don't "upgrade" your question, but post another one if you need more help. Upgrading doesn't work in these sites