# Lagrange multipliers code runs forever

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am writing a code for a Lagrange multipliers problem with three variables. 
My code looks like this:

```
 f[x_, y_, z_] := (m1 x + m2 y + m3 z)/Sqrt[m1^2 x + m2^2 y + m3^2 z]
 g[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z - 1
 Minimize[{f[x, y, z], g[x, y, z] == 0, 
           m1 > 0, m2 > 0, m3 > 0, x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}, {x, y, z}]
```

But it keeps running with no answer, why is that?

Comment: Given the equality constraint `g`, why don't you simplify the problem to a two-variable one, `Minimize[{f[x, y, 1 - x - y], x + y < 1, m1 > 0, m2 > 0, m3 > 0,  x > 0, y > 0}, {x, y}]`, and furthermore solve for the first-order conditions instead of using brute-force minimisation?

Comment: You won't get a min if all `ms` are different :)

Comment: Why is that, belisarius?

Answer (score 2):

I would first note that the problem you are posing can be reduced to a two-variable one by substituting in your inequality constraint, to eliminate `z`. I note that your constraint `g` implies `x + y < 1`.

```
Minimize[{f[x, y, 1 - x - y], x + y < 1, m1 > 0, m2 > 0, m3 > 0, 
  x > 0, y > 0}, {x, y}]
```

I then tried solving the *unconstrained* problem by differentiating the value function to get the first-order conditions and `Solve`ing for them:

```
Solve[{D[f[x, y, 1 - x - y], x] == 0, 
  D[f[x, y, 1 - x - y], y] == 0}, {x, y}]
```

This yields an empty set `{}`.

Traditionally, when solving the Lagrangian, you include the constraint in the equations to be solved, like this:

```
Solve[{D[f[x, y, 1 - x - y] + lambda (1 - x - y), x] == 0, 
  D[f[x, y, 1 - x - y] + lambda (1 - x - y), y] == 0}, {x, y}]
```

This gives a (complicated) answer almost immediately. I would note that setting lambda (the Lagrangian multiplier) to zero in the solution generates a division by zero, confirming that lambda is non-zero and the required constraint `g` is an equality.

Comment: Here is what I get:

Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>

Solve[{D[f[x, y, 1 - x - y] + lambda (1 - x - y), x] == 0, 
  D[f[x, y, 1 - x - y] + lambda (1 - x - y), y] == 0}, {x, y}]

Can you help me interpret this?

Answer (score 1):

To confirm @belisarius comment:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := (m1 x + m2 y + m3 z)/Sqrt[m1^2 x + m2^2 y + m3^2 z]
g[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z - 1   

 L = f[x, y, z] + λ g[x, y, z];
 Solve[{Grad[L, {x, y, z}] == 0, g[x, y, z] == 0, m1 > 0, m2 > 0, 
 m3 > 0, x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}, {x, y, z, λ}]
{}

Simplify[Reduce[{Grad[L, {x, y, z}] == 0, g[x, y, z] == 0, m1 > 0, 
   m2 > 0, m3 > 0, x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}, {x, y, z, λ}], 
 m1 > 0 && m2 > 0 && m3 > 0]
```

[image]

calculated with Mma 10.2 on Windows 10